# How to send requests to Cloud Run only from the app?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Subscription based iOS app I'm building uses Cloud Run service invoked via HTTPS request.
How can I make sure that the request can only be invoked by app owners(from the app)?

I've looked at Google Sign-In authentication, but I don't think it is applicable in my case as only those subscribed to the app should have the access, not just those with Gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

I think without a Google Sign-in involved, your question has nothing to do with Cloud Run and can be generalized as:

> How to send requests to to a backend app only from its mobile app?

So I'll answer that.

You'll find out that you need some form of "authentication" to prove that you're on a mobile app as a "user". To achieve that, you need some form of *sign-in*.

You may try to ship a secret (like a token or private key) in the application and use that to authenticate, but this will be susceptible to:

1. exfiltration of the private they from the application bundle through reverse engineering
2. applying a man-in-the-middle attack to the HTTPS request (and therefore the token) by trusting a root CA on the device and using e.g. `mitmproxy` to decrypt the request as plaintext.

In reality, there's no way to fully secure iOS/Android <=> backend communication that. Even the largest apps like Twitter, Instagram etc have their APIs reverse engineered all the time and invoked from non iOS/Android clients as the requests can be spoofed.

---

If you want to authenticate your existing users, you should figure out how these people login to your app. This could be simple `username:password` in `Authentication: Basic [...]` header, or something more complicated like OAuth2 which is what apps like Facebook, Twitter implement under the covers for their mobile apps.

Then you would validate that Authentication header in your Cloud Run application code yourself.

So again, I don't think this is a problem specific to Cloud Run, or any cloud provider.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm looking at OAuth2 with PKCE technique which looks promising. Can't find a good example of how it's implemented with Google Cloud Run. I've created a service account which has permission to invoke the container. I don't need to track/authorize each user.

Comment: I found this example (https://github.com/stephendarling/cloud-run-flask-oauth2/tree/ac2ae76c492e679a52e638c7b1f79041f3c20510) (which authenticates to the Cloud Run endpoint via self-signed JWT in exchange for token). This is exactly what I need, but I want to add PKCE. I'm confused as to where do I send code_verifier and code_challenge? If I do the verification in my container, how would that link to Cloud Run authorization.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is for your API to only be called when your users are authenticated in your app, I would recommend implementing one of the two solutions [described on this page](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users):
[Using Google Sign-in](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users#using_google_sign-in) or [Firebase Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users#using_or_firebase_authentication)